# Two graphs G and F are isomorphic iff there is a bijection between E(G) an E(F)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I want to check if the following statement is true:

G and F are isomorphic graphs iff there exists a bijection f: E(G) -> E(F)

Comment: What does your notations mean? A bijection $f:E(G) \to E(F)$ only means the two graphs have the same cardinality of edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not enough. It must preserve adjacency.

Say $G= \{1,2,3\}$ with edges $12$ and $13$

and $ F= \{a,b,c,d\}$ with edges $ab$ and $cd$.

Clearly we have a bijection between edges but the graphs are not isomorphic.